# Run a thread in android after one thread completes its execution

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want run run a thread after one thread completes its execution.

Here I am using progress bar, after progress bar completes the method do1() should execute but when I am run the application the application force close.

here is my code..

```
         public void onenc(View view) {
          progressBar = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("Ecoding Text ...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();

        //reset progress bar status
        progressBarStatus = 0;

        //reset filesize
        fileSize = 0;


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

              // process some tasks
              progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

              // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
              try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

              // Update the progress bar
              progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                }
              });
            }

            // ok, file is downloaded,
            if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // close the progress bar dialog
                progressBar.dismiss();

            }


          }
           }).start();

        Thread tt =new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
        do1();

         try {
                Thread.sleep(1100);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

              }
           });
        tt.start();

      }
```

I have also tried AsyncTask but both run simultaneously.

Please help me I am a newbie in android.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

After AsyncTask

```
      class MyFirstTask extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                return null;
                //Do Stuff
            }
           public void progressUpdate(Integer progress) {
               new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                        while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                          // process some tasks
                          progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

                          // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
                          try {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }

                          // Update the progress bar
                          progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                              progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                            }
                          });
                        }

                        // ok, file is downloaded,
                        if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                            // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // close the progress bar dialog
                            progressBar.dismiss();

                        }


                      }
                       }).start();
           }
           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
               //Call your next task
               Thread tt =new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
            do1();

             try {
                    Thread.sleep(1100);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  }
               });
            tt.start();
           }
      }
```

Now not even a single thread is executing the application force closes

After Another Update

```
            class MyFirstTask extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                  new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                        while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                          // process some tasks
                          progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();

                          // your computer is too fast, sleep 1 second
                          try {
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }

                          // Update the progress bar
                          progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                              progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                            }
                          });
                        }

                        // ok, file is downloaded,
                        if (progressBarStatus >= 100) {

                            // sleep 2 seconds, so that you can see the 100%
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(2000);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // close the progress bar dialog
                            progressBar.dismiss();

                        }


                      }
                       }).start();

                return null;
                //Do Stuff
            }
           public void progressUpdate(Integer progress) {

           }
           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

               do1();
               //Call your next task
        /*     Thread tt =new Thread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
            do1();

             try {
                    Thread.sleep(1100);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  }
               });
            tt.start();*/
           }
      }
```

Now the function do1() executes before progress bar completes.

**Finally Solved it....Here is the answer.
Hope it will help others**

```
         class MyFirstTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
              super.onPreExecute();
              progressBar.show();


          }  
          @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


              int i=0;
                while(fileSize<100)
                {
                    fileSize=fileSize+1;
                     publishProgress(""+(int)(fileSize));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                       
                }

                 publishProgress(""+(int)(fileSize));

                return null;


            }
           public void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
               progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
           }
           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               progressBar.dismiss();
               do1();


           }
      }
```

Comment: When the app crashes? is it before or after the progress bar finish? or before start?

Comment: crashes Before start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Thread() at all. Use AsyncTask as it makes life easier and implement the onPostExecute() method to call the next AsyncTask

```
class MyFirstTask extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do Stuff that takes ages (background thread)
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){   
            doStuff();
            Thread.sleep(1000L); //sleep because I'm just tired
            publishProgress(i);
            Thread.sleep(2000L); //sleep some more
        }
    }
   @Override
   public void progressUpdate(Integer progress) {
       //Update progress bar (ui thread)
       progressBar.setProgress(progress);

   }
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
       //Call your next task (ui thread)
       new MyNextTask().execute();
   }
```

Start your first task

```
new MyFirstTask().execute();
```

Comment: I have used this but another thread starts before first one finishes.

Comment: @AmitKhurana it shouldn't. If you dont execute() your next task until first task executes PostExecute() they should run one after the other. I've changed my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I have updated the code but still it is giving error.

Comment: Dont use Thread() at all. Do all your 'work' in doInbackground() it will run on a background thread. onPostExecute() runs back on the UI thread again so you can update UI etc

Comment: Still not working the function do1() executes before progress bar completes.

Comment: @AmitKhurana Android Dev often requires multi-threading scenarios where use of AsyncTask and a base knowledge of Java threading will go a long way http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @AmitKhurana remove the use of new Thread completely. In doInbackground call publishProgress(int); which will call progressUpdate(int progress) on AsyncTask :)

Comment: can you please write the code I am not getting it....also if i will remove thread then how i will be able to call sleep()?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use join() method.

```
Thread first = new Thread();
Thread secThread =new Thread();
first.start();
first.join();
secThread.start();
```

but do not do this on main thread.

Comment: This is not ideal as the main thread will block until threadOne completes

Comment: what is the exception you are getting.